# Is there a tool for labeling/annotating images using custom weights?

Tags: annotations, yolo, dataset

I´ve trained a model on YOLOv5 for detecting custom objects. Is there a tool to use those weights to label new images showing the same classes?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Do you mean you want to run object detection on some images and use detected boxes as new labels for you images?

Comment: Yes! It detects them pretty fine on my new images, so it would be great to use it for new boxes.

Comment: For this purpose you can use YOLOV5's own detection script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> python detect.py img.jpg --save_txt

If you want to filter detections by class, try this

> python detect.py img.jpg --save_txt --class 0 2 3

The example will keep those objects belonging to classes 0, 2, and 3.